# Blackberry Torch Simulator and EditField Problem

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-torch

The Blackberry Torch is showing some wierd behaviour.  I have subclassed EditField only for visual stylings.  In the main application, I instantiate 2 of these custom EditFields and set the style bit to `EditField.FILTER_REAL_NUMERIC` in order to limit input to numbers.  These EditFields are then placed in a custom GridFieldManager along with some label fields which are un-focusable.

If I touch (in the simulator) directly on one these EditFields, the full qwerty key pad is displayed.  At this point, if I touch either of the EditFields that do not have focus, the correct key pad is displayed.  The same is true if I use the trackpad to scroll the focusable fields; the correct key pad is displayed.

Is this a known issue, or did forget something?

NOTE:  I have no idea if this is an issue on Torch device, since my office does not yet have a Torch device.

**UPDATE:**  It looks like this related to the custom GridFieldManager that manages this field.  This custom code is only for determining where focus should go:

```
public ExGridFieldManager(int rows, int columns, long style) {
        super(rows, columns, style );
    } // END contructor -----------------------------------------------------------------

    /* PROTECTED METHODS ----------------------------------------------------------------------- */

    // handle focus gain on container
    protected void onFocus( int direction )
    {
        if ( direction > 0 )    // focus came from previous field
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < this.getFieldCount(); i++)
            {
                if (this.getField(i).isFocusable())
                {
                    this.getField(i).setFocus();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        else if ( direction < 0 ) // catch case where focus came from following field
        {
            for(int i = this.getFieldCount() - 1; i >= 0 ; i--)
            {
                if (this.getField(i).isFocusable())
                {
                    this.getField(i).setFocus();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    } // END onFocus() ------------------------------------------------------------------

    protected void paint( Graphics g ) {
        super.paint(g);
    } // END paint() --------------------------------------------------------------------

    // catch touch on a given inside this manager and set focus appropriately
    protected boolean touchEvent( TouchEvent event ) {
        int index; // for holding index of field where touchEvent ocurred

        if ( event.getEvent() == TouchEvent.CLICK ) {
            index = this.getFieldAtLocation( event.getX(1), event.getY(1) );

            if ( index > -1 )
                this.getField(index).setFocus();
        }
        return false;
    } // END touchEvent() ---------------------------------------------------------------

    /* PUBLIC METHODS -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

    // determines when this manager should and should not recieve focus
    public boolean isFocusable()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i< this.getFieldCount(); i++)
        {
            if (this.getField(i).isFocusable())
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    } // END isFocusable() --------------------------------------------------------------
} // END class ====================================================================================
```

**UPDATE 2:**  I am targeting Blackberry OS version 5.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the GridFieldManager in Blackberry OS 5.0.  I found a custom one [here](http://www.assembla.com/code/psu-edu-sweng500/subversion/nodes/trunk/rimapp/src/com/thinkingblackberry/GridFieldManager.java), subclassed directly from `net.rim.device.api.ui.Manager`, that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

use `FILTER_NUMERIC` as style bit.

Comment: As opposed to FILTER_REAL_NUMERIC?

Comment: i mean instead of `FILTER_REAL_NUMERIC` use `FILTER_NUMERIC`.

Comment: Setting the style bit to FILTER_NUMERIC does not work.  The same problem as mentioned above, and the decimal point is missing, hence the need FILTER_REAL_NUMERIC.

Comment: well my editfields with filter_numeric behave as it is supposed to do. when i touch one of them only numeric input displays on virtual keyboard. i think there might be another problem with your editfield

Comment: I was thinking that, but I can not figure out where.  The stack trace is exactly what it should be.