# Question Regarding EditFields and VirtualKeyboards

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-torch

I have posted a StackOverflow question about the [behaviour of the VirtualKeyboard on the Torch simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446892/blackberry-torch-simulator-and-editfield-problem).  As a follow up question, where does an EditField get it's reference to the Virtual Keyboard on touch devices?

I am trying to display a Real Numeric keyboard (the proper style bit is set on the EditField), yet the keyboard that is displayed (on the Torch simulator when the slider is closed) is a "qwerty" keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.  The answer can be found on my StackOverflow question ["Blackberry Torch Simulator and EditField Problem"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446892/blackberry-torch-simulator-and-editfield-problem).  The trick as to subclass directly from Manager.

The issue was the GridFieldManager, which I had subclassed.  I am still not sure how that caused the behaviour I described above.  If anyone has any idea please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

You can add NullField before the EditField. NullField is the invisible Field with FOCUSABLE property.

Answer (score 0):

For the follow up question - through the Screen, for example:

```
    // hide the virtual keyboard by default
    final Screen screen = getScreen();
    if (screen != null) {
        final VirtualKeyboard virtualKeyboard = screen.getVirtualKeyboard();
        if (virtualKeyboard != null) {
            virtualKeyboard.setVisibility(VirtualKeyboard.HIDE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tried that, and it was still shoeing the wrong virtual keyboard.